# ODL Fluorine RpcRegistration is Deprecated How are RPCs Registered now?

Tags: java, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I'm attempting to create a feature on the new ODL version for Fluorine. With this new release the package: `org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.api.RpcProviderService.RpcRegistration` is deprecated. When going to the documentation for that package it references a new package: `org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.api.RpcProviderService` that has a function `registerRpcImplementation(Class<S> type, T implementation)`.

This is great; however, there's no documented example i can find on how to actually implement that function. Here's how the RPC's used to be registered:

```
    private RpcRegistration<NewFeatureService> serviceRegistration;

    public void init()
    {
        serviceRegistration = rpcProviderRegistry.addRpcImplementation(NewFeatureService.class, new NewFeatureImpl(dataBroker, ds, props));
    }
```

Another problem with the lack of documentation for this new library/package is that the blueprint.xml for the new feature is also changed due to RpcRegistration package changing.

Has anyone implemented a new feature on Fluorine or have an example to show how this is implemented?

I'm expecting that this isn't too difficult i just haven't seen an example (even on the official wiki) on how to properly do this.

Answer (score 1):

The method on the mdsal RpcProviderService is basically the same - just the named changed to registerRpcImplementation and the return type is ObjectRegistration which is also the base interface for RpcRegistration.